# Nested attributes that do not belong to the current object using has_many :through

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, nested-attributes, has-many-through

My end goal is to be able to add costumes to an agreement in the agreement view, regarless of whether or not they exist in the Costume database yet. My main difficulty is that a costume does not belong to an agreement, they exist independently but can be added to an agreement. If a new costume is added that isn't in the Costume database, it will add it to the database. Is there a way to do this? I can't find a tutorial about this anywhere. If I could get the controller from [this](http://craiccomputing.blogspot.com/2013/11/habtm-relationships-in-rails-4.html) post, I think that is all I need. I just need to create one costume every time the form is displayed. Thanks so much.

My models are as follows:

```
# app/models/agreement.rb
class Agreement < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :costumes, join_table: :agreement_costumes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :costumes, :reject_if => :all_blank
end

# app/models/costume.rb
class Costume < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :agreements, join_table: :agreement_costumes
end

# app/models/agreement_costume.rb
class AgreementCostume < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :agreement
  belongs_to :costume
end
```

My agreement controller is as follows:

```
class AgreementsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_agreement, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # Some methods ommitted

  # GET /agreements/new
  def new
    @agreement = Agreement.new
    @agreement.costumes.build
    @costumes = Costume.all
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_agreement
      @agreement = Agreement.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def agreement_params
      params.require(:agreement).permit(:name, :phone, :email, :mailbox, :wesid, :title, :start, :end, :due, :financer, :employee, :costumes_attributes => [:cid, :description, :wd, :back, :photo])
    end
:end
```

And finally, the agreement view

```
<%= form_for(@agreement) do |f| %>
  <% if @agreement.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@agreement.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this agreement from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @agreement.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <!-- Agreement fields omitted -->

  <%= f.fields_for :costumes do |c| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= c.label :cid %><br>
      <%= c.number_field :cid %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= c.label :description %><br>
      <%= c.text_field :description %>
    </div>
    <!-- etc with costume fields -->
  <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials on Nested Attributes. Here is one that specifically mentions creating new "tasks" through the user form.http://www.sitepoint.com/complex-rails-forms-with-nested-attributes/ I think what you are running into is that you have defined a join table, but are using two "has many through" relations. I think you want a "has and belongs to many" relationship in Rails. See: http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes

Comment: I just watched that Railscast, it's probably not what you are looking for. Here's an example project on github that is about accepting nested attributes for a HABTM relation: https://github.com/tylergannon/accepts-nested-attributes-habtm-example

Comment: The railscast isn't really what I'm looking for. I don't want to display my other model, I want to create new instances. In terms of that rails cast, it would be like if there was an "other" box that when I put something there, it added it to the model, and you would see it in the check boxes every other time. Please let me know if I'm being unclear.

Comment: You want to be able to create a new costume through the new agreement form, right?

Comment: An agreement can have many costumes, right? But if the same costume can show up in many agreements (i.e. it's being reused) you would probably want HABTM instead of HMT.

Comment: My gut instinct is that you want a nested form in your agreement form. If you have a list of costumes available to the new agreement, you could then have a "new costume" form nested at the end of the list. Or even use Javascript to open a sub form for a new costume using AJAX.

Comment: This has some good tips: http://craiccomputing.blogspot.com/2013/11/habtm-relationships-in-rails-4.html

Comment: I'll take a look at that and let you know. You are right in your assumptions about costumes and agreements. I'll try the HABTM.

Comment: That seems to be doing the trick when I work in the rails console (i.e. create an agreement, and a costume with `Agreement.new` and `Costume.new`, and doing a `agreement.costumes.append(new_costume)` and `agreement.save`. That puts it in the database correctly, but my question is, what does the `create` method in the Agreement controller look like?

Comment: Isn't that the purpose of the `.build` method? Getting out of my depth, but if you use the nested ajax form, your nested form for the new Costume would call the `create` method in the Costume controller. There is probably a way to do it directly, passing the Costume attributes in a hash in your `.permit(...`

Comment: I think it must be something like that. If I could just see the controllers on the craiccomputing site, it would be everything I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in your Agreement controller if you want to create new costumes there.

```
class Agreement < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :agreement_costumes
  has_many :costumes, through: :agreement_costumes

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :costumes, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => :false,
end
```

and then in the `agreements#new` action in your Agreements controller you build a costume entry

```
def new
  @agreement = Agreement.new
  @agreement.costumes.build
  @costumes = Costumes.all
end
```

`@agreement.costumes.build` creates a blank instance of a costume, related to this agreement. You then access the params of that costume in the form using `:costumes` Don't forget to whitelist your nested params in your Agreements controller:

```
def agreement_params
  params.require(:agreement).permit(:name, :phone, :email, :mailbox, :wesid,
   :title, :start, :end, :due, :financer, :employee, costumes_attributes[:name, :price, :id])
end
```

Now your form has to have a place to choose existing costumes from a list and/or add a new one.

```
<%= f.label :costumes, "Costumes" %>
<%= f.collection_select :costumes, :agreement_id, :id, :name, price, {}, {multiple: true} %>

<strong>Add a new costume</strong>
<%= f.fields_for :costumes do |c|
  <%= c.label :name %>
  <%= c.text_field :name %>
    <br>
  <%= c.label :price %>
  <%= c.number_field :price %>
    <br>
<% end %>
```

This should get you most of the way there. I've had to guess at some of your code, so this isn't going to be a cut and paste answer. You'll need to build what you can off of this and probably do a little more Googling here and there. If you wanted to have a popup form to add a costume to the list on the fly and then be able to choose it in the collection_select, you would have to turn on Turbo_links in your app, create a Javascript popup form. Then use AJAX to submit the form, save the costume to the database, run another `.js.erb` file that would then update the `collection_select` text list using a reload of just that list via your Javascript. It's actually probably easier than having a new costume form nested in this form.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I edited my post and added a bit of info if that helps. I don't think I need the f.collection_select since no one will be selecting from existing costumes. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Ah, that was not clear, I thought you wanted access to the previously created costumes. If a new agreement is never going to use old costumes, why do you have them in a many-to-many relation? If a costume is only used in one agreement, Agreements would have many costumes, but Costumes would belong to one Agreement. Just because code might state that a Costume belongs to an Agreement, they still exist independently. These relations just cause Rails to give you some methods auto-magically. So you can basically do some simple joining without even setting up a temporary table or writing the SQL.

Comment: Costumes may be reused, but there will be thousands. The `cid` property will be unique to each costume. Costumes can be created independently, or through the agreements form. The idea being that someone creating an agreement can just put in the `cid` property and we will get the rest from the database. That's why I want the many-to-many relation. I am also building a database of costumes. Is that better?

Comment: Do you consider this solved? Does your code work now that you are using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and `.build`?

Comment: Almost. It works perfectly in the console, but the `f.fields_for` in the view doesn't render anything, strangely.

Comment: Hmmm.. have you tried `@costumes` instead of `:costumes` in that part of the form?

Comment: No, scratch that. I think your problem lies in that you have created 3 new costumes for the agreement. I think you need to change the first form_for in some way, just can't remember... let me check.

Comment: Change your `<% f.fields_for :costumes do |c| %>` to `<%= f.fields_for :costumes do |c| %>` . per this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489431/nested-forms-in-rails-3-1

Comment: `<%` in `.fields_for` was deprecated after Rails 3.0 to `<%=`.

Comment: Ok. I see everything now. I updated the code again. The error lies somewhere in the `agreement_params` method of the agreement controller. With the way it is currently setup, I get the following message when I submit: `Unpermitted parameters: cid, description, wd, photo, back`. Thanks again for all of this help.

Comment: Here is the whole message if it helps (some fields ommitted):
`Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"g7nvrVXX07uDGozzR5KPdIhxlY5P6gdBgv+/2p7mARk=", "agreement"=>{"name"=>"test 7", ...,  "employee"=>"", "costumes_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"cid"=>"", "description"=>"test 7", "wd"=>"", "photo"=>"", "back"=>"0"}}}, "commit"=>"Create Agreement"}
Unpermitted parameters: cid, description, wd, photo, back`

Comment: Figured it out. The correct params method has `:costumes_attributes => [:cid, :photo, :description, :wd, :back]`. Thanks for all your help!